# How to get project version in gitlab-ci.yml file from the .net project file?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am converting my project from Jenkins to GitLab CI. There is a .sh file which I am executing from .gitlab-ci.yml file where I am extracting the version from the project file using following statement:

VERSION=$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=)[^<]+" /Service.csproj

I am getting the project version and this is working fine.
How can I run the above statement in .gitlab-ci.yml file and assign the version value to a variable?
I tried running statement but I am getting error like invalid option "P"

Comment: There seems to be no closing parenthesis to your `$(`.

Answer (score 2):

I use in my example the `sed` command

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - VERSION=$(sed -n "s/<Version>\(.*\)<\/Version>/\1/p" Service.csproj)
    - echo $VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the command in a [script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script) block, so your gitlab-ci.yml could look like this:

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - VERSION=$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=)[^<]+" Service.csproj | xargs)
    - echo $VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow above grep didn't work for me. Below works for me.

```
$VERSION=[regex]::match((Get-Content .\AssemblyFileVersion.cs), "AssemblyFileVersion\(`"(.*)`"\)").Groups[1].Value'
```